# Python: How can I iterate 20 columns and find the top column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new and maybe my question is silly so I apologise in advance.

Basically I have data like this,

```
ID | Scope 1 | Scope 2 | Scope 3 | Scope 4 | ... | Scope 30|   
1  | True    |  True   | True    |  False  | ... |   True  |
2  | True    |  True   | True    |  False  | ... |   False |
3  | True    |  True   | True    |  False  | ... |   True  |
4  | True    |  False  | False   |  False  | ... |   False |
```

I would like to make a new column called Top Scope and have the highest scope number that has True as output.

I am trying for loop but I am not failing. :( 
Can you please help me? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please share your tries ;)

Comment: And how does your data structure look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for all columns, check order of columns by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and slicing and last use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['Top Scope'] = df.filter(like='Scope').idxmax(axis=1)
#seelcting all columns without first with reversed order
#df['Top Scope'] = df.iloc[:, :0:-1].idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
   ID  Scope 1  Scope 2  Scope 3  Scope 4  Scope 30 Top Scope
0   1     True     True     True    False      True  Scope 30
1   2     True     True     True    False     False   Scope 3
2   3     True     True     True    False      True  Scope 30
3   4     True    False    False    False     False   Scope 1
```

More general solution is necessary for avoid wrong output if all `False` values with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` per rows:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Scope').iloc[:, ::-1]
df['Top Scope'] = np.where(df1.any(axis=1), df1.idxmax(axis=1), 'no match')
print (df)
   ID  Scope 1  Scope 2  Scope 3  Scope 4  Scope 30 Top Scope
0   1     True     True     True    False      True  Scope 30
1   2     True     True     True    False     False   Scope 3
2   3     True     True     True    False      True  Scope 30
3   4     True    False    False    False     False   Scope 1
4   5    False    False    False    False     False  no match
```